# how to reference image from another project in same solution in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have 3 projects in the same solution (`AdminArea`, `sarir`, `datalayer`).

I save images in `wwwroot/Images` in `AdminArea` project,m and I want to reference them in the `sarir` project. How can I do that? Thank you

This is not working for me:

```
src="@Url.Content("/AdminArea/wwwroot/Images/SliderImages/@item.ImageName")"
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages ?

Comment: Are images really in "wwwrooot/Images" or "wwwroot/Images"?  Please provide an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Shared Folder or Virtual Directory:

Create a shared folder that both projects can access. You can either create a physical folder and ensure both projects have access to it, or create a virtual directory within the sarir project that points to the AdminArea's wwwroot/Images directory.

- Physical Folder:

Place your images in a shared physical directory accessible by both projects. Ensure the projects have the necessary permissions to access this folder.

- Virtual Directory:

In the sarir project, you can set up a virtual directory that points to the wwwroot/Images folder of the AdminArea project in your Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
  {
   FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"..\AdminArea\wwwroot\Images")),
   RequestPath = "/SharedImages"
 });
```

1. Reference Image in HTML/Razor:

Once the shared folder or virtual directory is set up, you can reference the images in your sarir project's HTML/Razor views:

```
<img src="/SharedImages/SliderImages/@item.ImageName" alt="Image" />
```

Replace `/SharedImages/SliderImages/` with the correct path to your images within the shared directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add  middleware to your sarir project Program.cs:
:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\solutionname\AdminArea\wwwroot\Images", "SliderImages")),
    RequestPath = "/Images"
});
```

then in the html:

```
<img src="/Images/flower.PNG" width="100" height="200" alt="3" />
```

Comment: I use it and worked correctly

Comment: app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "AdminArea", "wwwroot", "Images")),
    RequestPath = "/Images"
});